# What is the proper way of making weak reference of Singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, singleton, reference-counting

I came across a situation where I am using `sharedClass` and in it I fetched data using blocks. There is a convention to use __weak reference inside blocks to prevent retain cycle.How do I create a weak reference of something which is going to remain alive throughout the app?

Here is the code what I did,

```
+ (instancetype)sharedPresenter {
    static PostCareListPresenter *presenterInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        presenterInstance = [[PostCareListPresenter alloc] init];
    });
        return presenterInstance;
}

- (void)getPostCareList:(NSDictionary*)pParameterDictionary
                success:(void(^)(NSData*responseData))pSuccessCallback
                failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))pFailureCallback {
    [[GSWebAccessManager sharedManager] invokePostCareList:pParameterDictionary success:^(NSData *responseData) {
        // Here I have to make a call to my private method using weak self.  [weakSelf somePrvateMethod]; 

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a singletone object is never to be destroyed you should not care if it is retained or not

Comment: should i use self instead of weakSelf?

Comment: sure. why not? you don't care about its retain count. it lives always

Comment: or you can use weakSelf if you wish to. it does not change a thing